# how to diagnose and fix performance issue with Office JS API

Tags: office-js

I am using Office JS API with Script Lab to develop a snippet which processes every paragraph of a Word document, and for each paragraph, sends an AJAX request to the server with the outline level and the HTML of the paragraph.

When the AJAX request is received by the server, the process on the server loads the HTML in WordPress and builds a hierarchy of WordPress Pages similar to the hierarchy of paragraphs in the Word document.

Everything works fine with a document of 1 or 3 pages, but with documents of more than 10 pages, I always get an error.

Script Lab displays that the component did not respond and had to restart it.

I have no error on the server side.

How to diagnose and fix this?

Comment: Please show us your code. Also, note these words from the article [Avoid using the context.sync method in loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern#writing-to-the-document): "Just as the commands in a synchronization batch job are queued, the batch jobs themselves are queued in Office, but Office supports no more than 50 batch jobs in the queue. Any more triggers errors. ..."

Comment: I have updated my code to send only one AJAX request with all the paragrahs and do the loop on each paragraph on the server side. It works fine now, thanks.